# Bionicpup64 8.0 + Windows7 + Ubuntu16.04LTS +GrubX

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grub4dos

I want to change my grub menu display/appearance. I also do not want to mess up what I have, everything works. I can boot all three OS.

Notes: 1) I had Windows(sda2(primary)) and Bionicpup64 8.0(sda6 (extended)). It worked. I want to add Ubuntu. My Ubuntu18 iso had errors. I had a 16 iso. So I added Ubuntu16(sda8(extended)). Plan to upgrade later

2) After Ubuntu16 install my grub menu showed Windows & Ubuntu, no Pup. I reinstalled Bionicpup64 8.0 in sda6. This time whatever Grub is included with Bionicpup64 8.0 found all the kernels and the menu gives all options and all is fine.

I just want to tweak the display. I've googled but can't find any of the files suggested for adding stuff to the grub settings. /boot/grub/grub.cfg, menu.lst, /etc/grub.d/..., etc. I have Grub4Dos boot loader config program installed. I've not used it because it's not clear what it will do and perhaps overwrite stuff I have now and that work. Ditto Legacy GRUB Config program.

I'm loathe to try any of the commands like grub-install update-grub for the same reason, fix something that's not broken

Is there a utility like FindGrubConfigFiles? Or something other than Grub4Dos. Grub4Dos looks like it wants to **rebuild/rewrite** - I don't see a **this-is-what-you-have-now option**.

Comment: Please be specific with releases, there is no Ubuntu 16, nor Ubuntu 18.  Ubuntu desktop and server releases are *yy.mm* in format, and *yy* is used for snap based specialist releases such as Ubuntu Core for IoT appliances.  You other off-topic OSes don't appear to be device releases, so is it an IoT release you're asking about?

Comment: From your description your MBR & thus `grub` is owned by Bionicpup, which is neither Ubuntu, nor official flavor of Ubuntu thus off-topic on this site.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic which provides other SE support sites if you don't want to use a Puppy Linux forum.

Comment: Apologies, guiv. Apologies if I caused offence to anyone. I'll ask elsewhere